# Methods of variational calculus in analytic number theory

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, analytic-number-theory, calculus-of-variations

What methods of calculus of variations have been used in analytic number theory?

I mean do Hamilton-Jacobi theory of PDE found usage in analytic number theory, which raises yet another question has PDE theory been used in analytic number theory? Please advise for literature that combines methods of VC and PDE in analytic number theory.

Thanks.

Comment: This will not qualify for analytic number theory, but it is number theory nonetheless. There is a variational principle in Arakelov theory, except that what is being minimized there is a height function rather than an action, and the conclusion is not a differential equation but the equidistribution of the Galois orbits of the points whose height is being minimized. This is in [Szpiro, Ullmo, Zhang: "Equirepartition des petits points," 1997]. And if you dig into the math underlying this, you'll find that PDE theory is also implied, via some non-trivial results on the heat equation.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov do you have an English translation of this article?

Comment: No, but here is a later article, in English, that proves a more general result: Yuan, Xinyi: "Big line bundles over arithmetic varieties," *Inventiones*, 2008. Those are based on the arithmetic Hilbert-Samuel formula, the proof of which involves some heat kernel asymptotics (cf. the paper by Bismut and Vasserot, or the more elementary one by Abbes and Bouche, referred to in Yuan's article). From there on the argument is variational, and in addition to that it is entirely similar to energy minimization.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I assume I will need to read Hartshorne sometime soon for Algebraic Geometry; I like all these interconnectedness between different fields of pure and applied maths.

Comment: For an application of calculus of variations in the theory of the Riemann zeta function, see Section 4 of Conrey's paper "More than two fifths of the zeros of the Riemann zeta function are on the critical line" (http://210.45.192.203/jsmath-3.6e/allpdf/morethan2_5.PDF)